# Exporting DSYM with Flash develop

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, mobile, flashdevelop, dsym

I'm trying to implement Crashlytic's into an AS3 iOS app. To work, Crashlytic's requires the dSYM file, however it is not created when exporting the IPA.
I've researched this issue and I can only find solutions for Flash Builder. 
Can anyone advise me on how to locate the dSYM, or how to export a build with the dSYM file?

Answer (score 1):

The dsYM file is created only on MAC (it will never be created on PC). It is created everytime you export your IPA but that file is discarded shortly after its creation if you do not explicitly check the check box in FB 4.7 to keep the exporting folder.